# Force Unwrapping a querySnapshot, Is there any better way to do this?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to swift & firebase and have this code to check if a user exists in my firebase database:

```
  COLLECTION_USERS.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error connecting to database")
        }
        else {
            if querySnapshot.isEmpty {

                print("SIGNED UP")
                
            }
        }
    }
```

A problem occurs at this line:

```
if querySnapshot.isEmpty {
```

I can solve it by doing,

```
if (querySnapshot!.isEmpty) {
```

Is this an okay practice to do?
I know that force unwrapping something is typically not advised, would it be okay in this situation or is there a different solution?

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: You can do the same as in the error branch, but either the error is `nil` then `snapshot` has a value and vice versa. By the way it's very bad practice to print a meaningless literal string rather than printing the unwrapped `error`. And in Swift both snake_case and UPPERCASE variable names are discouraged. The naming convention is lowerCamelCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better practice would be to check if the parameter is `nil` with a `guard`.
And only after this check evaluates the emptiness condition.

```
COLLECTION_USERS.whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error connecting to database")
        return
    }

    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error retrieving data")
        return
    }

    if snapshot.isEmpty {
        print("SIGNED UP")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks acceptable, it's just enforcing the value to be assumed to exist which it should be caught by the error first.